# Dashboard Camera - How to Fit a Supercapacitor

Tags: camera, supercapacitor

I do not have a background in electronics.

I am using a cheap Chinese sport camera as a dashboard camera – which seems to be a bad idea for the battery started to wear very fast. The battery swollen so much I couldn’t remove it from camera. I was able to remove it after it spent one night in the fridge.

The camera is configured to start when the power cable is inserted and to gracefully shut down when removed. Without battery, it starts fine, but it obviously can’t shut off correctly when unplugged – plus it does not keep the time (which seems to lead to some SW problems).

I disassembled the battery and kept the case and the connector/protection board (see the picture below). What I would like to do, if possible, is to fit some super-capacitors inside the case so as to allow correct shutdown and keep time for a day or two. I know cameras that are able to use super-capacitors, but they were designed for this.

1. Is it possible? What about the middle terminal? – the one that tells the kind of battery.
2. If possible, what is the diagram?
3. How large should be the capacitors? The camera has a display which cannot be turned off.

Thank you.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Supercapacitors are typically used to keep devices powered on long enough for them to wrap up critical processes in the event of a power loss. They'll often supply critical components for milliseconds to seconds. Something power-hungry like a camera won't be able to run off for long periods of time off a supercapacitor as if it were a battery.

Comment: @schadjo Seconds is all I need. [Mobius](https://youtu.be/yPX4ssAiplE) is a camera designed to work with battery or supercapacitors. [Mobius with supercapacitors test.](https://youtu.be/QGTVF-h3BF4)

Comment: _"I was able to remove it after it spent one night in the fridge"_ I'm going to have to give you a +1 for creativity there.

Comment: I doubt that this will work without some modifications to the circuit; a capacitor's voltage drops as it discharges, whereas a battery keeps a (mostly) constant voltage. A buck/boost converter might be needed to allow it to keep operating off a lower voltage than it expects. Your battery protection circuit also won't have a clue what's going on with the capacitor, since it expects a lithium-ion battery.